# QUERY TO REMOVE EACH ROWs WITH \N

Tags: sql

Hi i have two column any idea what to do?
i tried this query instead it deleted row that has values and i don't want it to delete row 678 with 1960 :

```
delete TableD
from Year
 Where A = 678 AND B = '\N'
```

[image: query to remove or skip every row with to delete every row with **\N**]

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server-2008`?

Comment: You say you have two tables but you show two columns. Then you have a delete statement that you claim deleted rows that would be impossible from the data posted. We need some real details to be able to help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: This query *won't* delete anything that doesn't have a newline. What is the question?

Comment: DELETE FROM TableD WHERE B = '\N'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from TableD tD
where tD.B = '\N'
```

if youre trying to delete rows with \n in column B

Answer (score 0):

delete TableD where b = '\N';
COMMIT;

Comment: There is no begin transaction so your commit is going to fail with "The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.".